# Using 'try' and 'exept' for handaling an error in an In-stagram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, bots, instagram

everybody, I'm a newbie in programming so please consider that my question might not be so intelligent.

I'm studying python but in the meantime, I'm looking through some code to understand it.

I was "creating" or better "coping" an Instagram bot from youtube.

Now I will attach here the code, but in summary, I'm trying to get some hashtags from Instagram and liking and commenting on the first post for each hashtag.

An error occurs every time someone disables the comments. I was thinking of using 'try' and 'except' to handle this error. But I'm not sure what is the correct way to do that

```
def getTopPosts(self):
    for hashtag in self.hashtags:
        self.browser.get(
            'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag + '/')
        time.sleep(2)

        links = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        def condition(link): return '.com/p/' in link.get_attribute('href')
        valid_links = list(filter(condition, links))

        for i in range(0, 9):
            link = valid_links[i].get_attribute('href')
            if link not in self.links:
                self.links.append(link)

def execute(self):
    for link in self.links:
        self.browser.get(link)
        time.sleep(1)

        self.browser.execute_script(
            "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(1)

        self.comment()
        time.sleep(2)

        self.like()

        self.price += 0.02
        sleeptime = random.randint(18, 28)
        time.sleep(sleeptime)

def comment(self):
    def comment_input(): return self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')
    comment_input().click()
    comment_input().clear()

    comment = random.choice(self.comments)
    for letter in comment:
        comment_input().send_keys(letter)
        delay = random.randint(1, 7) / 30
        time.sleep(delay)

    comment_input().send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Now my question is should I use 'try' in the function comment() or when I call it in the function execute(self)?

My aim is if the code in the comment function cannot be run without an error skip that and continue so that the program doesn't crash at this error.

I hope the question was understandable.
Because I'm a newbie I ask you to reply by sharing an example that maybe can help me understand how to do this in general also for future use, also a link to another source could be good as long as it contains examples.

Comment: I am not a fan of using try - except clauses to hide errors unless you know exactly how and why the error is caused. If not, you suppress an error which may later in the code cause new errors. By the way, you didn't post what the error was, a full Traceback gives clues to whomever might want to help you.

Comment: As this blog on [Robust exception handling](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/21/robust-exception-handling/) points out, exceptions are best practice is "Handle exceptions at the level that knows how to handle them". In this case is it comment or execute which best knows how to deal with the exception?  If you handle it in comment, then you could raise a different exception for execute to alert it to ignore the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, it is probably better to avoid creating unnecessary exceptions.

If using the Instagram API, you could use the `is_comment_enabled` attribute ([see documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media)).

something like:

```
def execute(self):
[...]
if self.is_comment_enabled:
    self.comment()
[...]
```

But if you're scraping, [a try/except block](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) is probably easiest:

```
def comment(self):
    try:
        [...]
    except:
        return false
```

Good luck!